# Javascript / jQuery - Scraping IMG SRC

Tags: javascript, jquery, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data using Javascript and the jQuery library.

So far so good. I am able to scrape data from between tags. For example I want to get the data from `<li>` tags, I do so as follows:

```
stuff_found = $(data).find('li');
```

However, if I try to get the src from an `<img>` tag by using the following code, only the first image is returned.

```
stuff_found =  $(data).find('img').attr();
```

I need to know how to return the full list (every image on the page) and not just the first in line.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to write the image selector to get only those that are inside `<li>` tags. Then you can traverse them with `.each()` or, if you really only need image `src` attribute values, `.map()`. For example:

```
var imageList = $('li img').map(function()
{
    return $(this).attr('src');
}).get();
```

Here in the code example this happens:

1. you first get all the images that are inside `<li>` tags - the `$('li img')` part.
2. Then with `.map()` you apply a function to go over all of them and extract a value. Basically what `.map()` does is that it takes a list, applies a given function to all elements of the list and returns the resulting list with the newly processed elements.
3. The part with `$(this).attr('src')` gets the actual `src` value from the image tag.
4. And finally, because jQuery returns it's own array type instead of a standard javascript array, you need to do `.get()` - that is what converts the returned object from jQuery array to a standard array.

Answer (score 0):

*every image on the page* ..?

```
$('li img').each(function(){
  var src = $(this).attr('src');
});
```

Or getting list of them -

```
var list = $('li img').map(function() {
              return $(this).attr('src');
           }).get();
```

Comment: I'm getting a bit confused with this to be honest.At the moment I have `stuff_found = $(data).find('li');`, which is then followed up in a for loop where I get each individual value using `var value = stuff_found[i].firstChild.nodeValue;`. What I actually want to do is this exact same thing, but I want the images source from inside each li element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img').each(function(){
    alert($(this).prop('src'));
});
```